# How to render text pixel-perfectly with subpixel antialising with Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, anti-aliasing, subpixel-rendering

I'm exporting a document to raster image with Illustrator and get this result:
[image: My result]
But I want to get this quality:
[image: Desired result]
It lookes more pixel-perfect and thin then the Illustrator's render. 
How do I setup Illustrator to render text pixel-perfectly? Also, is it possible to enable subpixel AA in it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

File - save for web

Select your output file (jpg|png|gif) and the quality

In the middle you will see a drop down under percent. Select "Type Optimized"

[image: type optimized]