# Why is my export so low res?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, image-quality

Can anyone tell me why my export from illustrator is so low res? It's 490 px wide so I thought it should still be sharp. Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

Below is the export with save for type enabled. See it ruins the type and doesn't improve the rez.
[image]

Comment: Save for "type optimized" instead of "art optimized", see relevant question [How to render text pixel-perfectly with subpixel antialising with Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54749/how-to-render-text-pixel-perfectly-with-subpixel-antialising-with-illustrator/54750#54750)

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: Helvetica neue light.

Comment: Try exporting a PNG at exactly 200% and then reducing the result back to 490px wide.

Comment: I think this thread might be good to read - [Why does Helvetica Neue look absolutely horrible in Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6347/why-does-helvetica-neue-look-absolutely-horrible-in-illustrator).

Comment: "   
Try exporting a PNG at exactly 200% and then reducing the result back to 490px wide. –  Yorik 6 mins ago" Tried that. Still the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little destructive but you might get some better results if you convert your text to outlines.

I've found in the past it's the easiest way to avoid Helvetica Neue destroying when it exports.

In fairness though, a 200% png is probably the best you'll get, your main problem seems to stem from the size of the elements in the graphic. 
When Illustrator exports your file It's rasterising all that lovely vector data into pixels - in some places (specifically the strapline under the logo) the text is thinner than a pixel so it compensates by making subpixels, and that's what is making things look blurry.

It's the same issue with the contact details, they either need to be a bigger font size or an extra font weight.

Hope that helps

Comment: @Will If you put your text to "outline", don't forget to save a copy with the text editable heehee!

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica is a horrible font for tiny raster text.  This has nothing to do with your resolution, it's simply because the image is small, and the text is too small to look good at that size.  Try a different font instead.  Segoe UI is one that's better designed for such small sizes.

Here's a comparison:

Your 1st Example, with Helvetica

[image]

Your 2nd Example, with Helvetica (Type optimised)

[image]

Segoe UI Light, 13px (Type optimised)

[image]

As you can see, there are no weird unevenly sized letters, especially noticeable in the word *Boundary*, or the word *lucra* in the Helvetica type optimised version.

Another thing you could do is increase the tracking very slightly to help with readability of the text, so that it's less cramped.

[image]

Comment: Did you switch the first two images? The second one (presumably type optimised) looks like the one in the question, and much worse than the first one.

Comment: No, the second one is what the OP says is type optimised. Yes it looks like crap.

Comment: Segoe UI still has a horrible lowercase t when Type optimised... or is that just part of the typeface? :P

Comment: @Vincent I think it's that way because of the way type optimisation works at small sizes - for the purpose of increasing readability.  I mean it's not totally perfect, but way better than Helvetica.

Answer (score 0):

Export at 4x size in illustrator then import into photoshop and reduce then save again. Very frustrating I know. Can be done as a batch in

Answer (score -1):

**File -> Save for Web** and then Export according to your requirement of Size. On that last page, you will find export preferences.

> If you find this helpful, please Upvote this.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

[image: Export screenshot]

Make your image size larger by multiplying by a ratio.