# Why is my logo pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, pixelation

I am very new to Illustrator. I've created a text only logo and exported it as a png. When I try to insert it as my email signature it becomes pixelated. How can I export it so it will not lose quality regardless of how small or large i need it to be. (I will also use it for letterhead, business cards and website).

Any help anyone could provide would be much appreciated!! thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what your logo looks like but I would also check out [How to render text pixel-perfectly with subpixel antialising with Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54749/how-to-render-text-pixel-perfectly-with-subpixel-antialising-with-illustrator/54750#54750). And there are a lot of questions on here already asked on how to export logos for various media platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Check the size,if it is in Points instead of inches then this could explain the pixelation. Try switching to inches and set it to at least 8.5 by 11. A PNG file preserves transparency,like if you didn't want the white background to appear behind it. A JPEG becomes pixelated when zoomed in,but if it has a high enough resolution then would be perfect for this instance. (Made the points mistake before and my exported work was very pixelated, I switched to inches and helped). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a size issue. While it's true your creations in Illustrator are vector images and do not pixelate, exporting other file types most certainly can. Check your document size and create a large version. You can then scale it down as needed when you export your file or redefine the size when in use. You should export your logo as a PNG file and not a JPG, because JPG's create pixels and lose quality every time you save them.

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more detail on how you're exporting your logo. What are the dimensions, what size do you want it to be displayed as, etc.

Rule of thumb is to export your image at different sizes pending on what you want to use them as. While png's are lossless, they still pixelate at various sizes, so best practice is to export individual files for each use (one image at an email signature size, one image at the size for a banner on your page, etc.).