# Bad distortion with Adobe Illustrator export uploaded to web

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design

[image: Exported from Illustrator]

[image: Posted on the web]

Sorry I am still learning plenty with Illustrator and cant seem to figure this out.  I tried exporting as PNG and also save for web option.  Both give me this weird blurry texturing effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render text pixel-perfectly with subpixel antialising with Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54749/how-to-render-text-pixel-perfectly-with-subpixel-antialising-with-illustrator)

Comment: Where are you uploading the images? If you are using social media sites such as Facebook, Twitter, or Instagram, then these sites process all images to jpeg, and add tons of compression, which degrades image quality.  If this is the case then it has nothing to do with Illustrator. If you check the file formats of the images you posted, you will see that the top one is PNG, and the bottom is JPEG.

Comment: It is difficult to know what exactly is the "distortion" you are referring to. Remember, we can't see the original and your two posted images look very similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know unless someone examine the original file.

But that kind of defects look like you used either a corupted original file or you simpy tried to vectorize a  low resolution bitmap. It looks like you do not have in reality one shape, but a bunch of small shapes grouped together.

A solution would be draw the shapes from start.

Answer (score -1):

Using Illustrator when exporting with "save for web (legacy)" 
try:

- PNG-24.
- Make sure you have transparency enabled if you want it
- Disabled "Interlaced"
- Make sure your image size is large enough, 256x256 is icon size, 500x500 standard avatar size, 1920x1080 standard web size, 1440x2560 hd wallpaper size.

If you could provide more detail on what and how you are trying to export that would help.

Comment: The files are attached to my post.  First the exported image saved to my pc, and then the image after uploaded to the web.  It is 1200x1200 square logo.  Exported it looks great, uploaded not so much.

Comment: @YungSock that seems to indicate that the service you upload it to recompresses the image. Then its not exactly a illustrator problem but a problem with the service you upload it to. Since we do not know what that is we can not give any advice.