# Illustrator logo export is pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, rasterization

I need a 290 px by 60 px image as my website logo. I designed the logo in Illustrator in 290 px by 60 px.

As it is a vector file, it doesn’t get pixelated, but whenever I export it as a PNG, it gets blurry and pixelated with slightest zooming:

[image: enter link description here]

I cannot increase the pixel dimension as it is the precise format for the website.

Is there any way of making it clear when exported?

Comment: How are you viewing the image?  In a browser? In another image viewer? Are you zooming in more than 100%? Is your computer's system zoom set to more than 100%?

Comment: Is it possible for you to upload the exported png?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render text pixel-perfectly with subpixel antialising with Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54749/how-to-render-text-pixel-perfectly-with-subpixel-antialising-with-illustrator)

Answer (score -1):

When you save it's converting to a raster image, so you'll have the pixels even though you start with a vector. Look in your settings (photo with red square). See if you can up your ppi, so that it is less pixelated when you save.
[image]

Comment: This setting is under "Document Raster Effects Settings" if you've already created the document.

Comment: This setting only affects pixel effects. So technically if you use pixel artboards it will not do anything for you.